# Calling getUserMedia on Chrome sometimes cause browser to freeze

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-chrome, webrtc

My company is developing a webrtc based video streaming solution using javascript on Angular 1.x. We are facing an issue, as some of the client's browsers are frozen when calling getUserMedia. The freeze is not consistent. We've managed to reproduce the issue with a device and then after killing the browser running the exact same code it worked, then it can repro again and so on.

Constraints example:

```
video: {
  deviceId: videoDevice.deviceId,
  width: { ideal: videoResolution.width },
  height: { ideal: videoResolution.height },
  facingMode: 'environment',
  frameRate: 30
}
```

Tried to set lower/higher and remove the frameRate, facingMode, and width/height on several tests

Tried using callbacks and promise as well, tried restarting the device, clearing the cache, updating the firmware, updating the browser, changing the resolution to be ideal/exact/min-max (several tests).

Searched the chromium bug pool, the specific device's OS issues and the general web. No lead yet.

Nothing works so far, and because the browser freeze we can't handle the issue gracefully. The only constant is that the devices that fail use chrome v60 and above on Android.

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks!